# Unity: Getting default Keyboard/Mouse in New Input System

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

Sometime ago I initialized the new Input System in Unity and somehow it came with WASD movement for keyboard and basic mouse actions already set in the Asset.

How can I get those basic actions out-of-the-package again?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the player input asset. It gives a reference to the initialized InputSystemAsset:
[image: Unity Player INput]

**EDIT:** It is also stored at the following path:

"*YourProjectName*\Library\PackageCache\com.unity.inputsystem@1.4.4\InputSystem\Plugins\PlayerInput/DefaultInputActions.inputactions"

It can also be opened in Unity Editor in the Packages Folder on the side pane:

[image: image showing packages path]

Answer (score 0):

Those are created when you put a Player Input component on a transform in the scene and then click on Create Actions.

For some reason Unity Docs guides you to create an empty InputAction Asset from the creation menu.